# Samsung i9300 touchscreen not working, stuck at welcome screen/language selection

Tags: touchscreen

My touchscreen is not responsive any more on my Samsung i9300 (Galaxy S3) - I don't know the reason. I successfully installed a stock ROM, but I'm stuck at the language selection/welcome screen.

The problem is simple: I need to select a language or to activate voice input to continue.

All hard buttons work and capacitive buttons (soft buttons) also work, but they are no help in selecting a language or activating voice input.

I found several solutions on that problem:

1. Summarized, it says to use an USB mouse connected to the phone by a OTG usb cable. I have tried it and I can not approve that, because the mouse is connected (lights on), but it is not recognized by the phone.
   Here's the source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/general/guide-unroot-reset-counter-touchscreen-t2074756
2. I had the idea of controlling the phone by using a USB keyboard connected to the phone like above (1.). This works a little bit better, because the phone receives key input, but very limited. CTRL+ALT+DEL works to reboot the phone. I wasn't able to figure out how to replace touchscreen functionality by using the keyboard resp. to select a language (at the welcome screen) where I'm originally stuck. There are a view keyboard combination lists on the internet.
3. Erica Griffn describes in this video the same issue and concludes, that she has no solution for it so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMG-_26NgXM

Is there any other solution I could try else?

A new diplay costs about $100 and a new S3 costs about $200. I don't want to exchange the phone or replace the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought a new display and replaced the old one. The procedure is more or less difficult, requires about 20 minutes time. Here's the tutorial I recommend: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rt8bl7oAPVU